# How to undo a Mercurial update

Tags: mercurial, undo

I was working in a Mercurial branch which had about 10 file changes in the working directory.  The working directory's parent was the tip of the branch.  Then I updated to a much older change set in the same branch forgetting that I had the 10 changes in the working directory.  Now I have hundreds of changes in the working directory and I have no idea what the 10 changes were that I started with.  Is there any way to undo the update to the older change set and get back to the state where I had just the 10 changes in my working directory?

To complicate matters, I control-c'd the update when beyond compare popped up asking me to merge a conflict.

I made a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for files with names ending in `.orig` in your working directory. Those are backups for the original version.

Unfortunately this is a place where mercurial's UI is not very safe by default. I'd suggest adding an alias either overriding the default behavior of `hg update` or adding an alias that does `hg update --check`, which would have avoided this.